# Kernel and Rootfs booting through tftp

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, u-boot, tftp

Task: to load kernel and rootfs image and execute into the ram without storing onto the spi flash

I loaded flashable image (zimage at 0x200000) and flashable rootfs (jffs2 at 0x200000+offset)

`tftp zimage 0x200000` `tftp jffs2 0x200000+offset` `bootm 0x200000 0x200000+offset`

It is giving me this error:

```
Root-NFS: No NFS server available, giving up.
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy.
VFS: Cannot open root device "ram0" or unknown-block(2,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
1f00        256 mtdblock0 (driver?)
1f01        256 mtdblock1 (driver?)
1f02       2048 mtdblock2 (driver?)
1f03      13824 mtdblock3 (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

And sometimes :
Bad Magic Number

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Write here your bootargs and bootcmd makros

Comment: *"I loaded ... flashable rootfs (jffs2 ... "* -- A JFFS2 image cannot be used in RAM as if it were an initrd or initramfs; it has to be accessed from a MTD device.  The error message you posted, *"Root-NFS: No NFS server available..."* does not agree with your stated goal, i.e. you must have configured for something else.

Comment: bootargs : root=/dev/ram0 rootfstype=jffs2 rw console=ttyMCS mem=64M@0x0

Comment: - sawdust, NFS support was enabled during kernel build, it does searches through and then revert back to the RAM0 device, still the same issue : Bad Magic Number

Comment: *"root=/dev/ram0 rootfstype=jffs2"* -- **These kernel parameters are incompatible.** As I already wrote, JFFS2 has to be accessed from a MTD device.  According to [this site](http://wiki.buici.com/xwiki/bin/view/Embedded+Linux/Mounting+JFFS2+Images+in+RAM), there is a MTD driver that is usable as a ramdisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sawdust, you were right. jffs2 cannot be used in RAM as if it were an initrd or initramfs.

i successfully loaded both images onto the ram and executed onto the ram itself based on EXT2 filesystem.

Bootargs: `setenv bootargs root=/dev/ram0 console=ttyMCS mem=64M@0x0 init=/bin/sh`

Answer (score 0):

As per your bootargs provided in comment use

```
root=/dev/ram0 rootfstype=jffs2 rw initrd=0x200000+offset,16M console=ttyMCS mem=64M@0x0
```

here XM is the size of initrd, if it is 8 MB give 8M

You haven't provided the offset of initrd in boot command, because of that kernel couldn't find the ramdisk image and gives `not syncing: VFS:`. Just add `initrd=0x200000+offset,16M` as above.